# Why didn't Ranma stay in China after getting the curse?

Tags: ranma

Why didn't Ranma and Genma stay in China after getting the curse? They got the curse there in the first place. Also, if the only way to be cured was to go to China again and visit the cursed springs, then why don't they? Ranma could've swam back to China anytime he wanted and he actually planned to during the episode where Ranma was finding the cure for Akane after being attacked by Shampoo with her Xi Fa Xiang Gao technique. What's keeping Ranma in Japan? There were episode where Ranma and Genma discussed about Ranma going back to China but for some reason, Ranma ended up staying for whatever reason, probably something about inheriting the dojo. But Ranma can always return so why doesn't he?

Comment: I've read the complete manga and I suspect it is because plot. In the end, Ranma is a light comedy and healing the curse would take the core element from it. If you want a more story-driven answer, I would suspect Ranma personally got used to it, occasionally likes it (don't tell me he never played with himself while being a girl, that simply nonsense for a teenager), but can never admit it because it would brand him a pervert by society (at least by the people who know the secret).